# MVC 4.0 model has null values after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null, http-post

First things first: I know there've been questions like that, I've read lots of them but none of them helped. I have a simple action sending model to the view (all hiddenfor fields are correct from what I see) but the post action doesn't get some of the properties. Here is the code.

Controller:

```
//
// GET:
public ActionResult EditComputer(int id)
{
    IDataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    var computer = dataProvider.GetComputer(id);
    return View(computer);
}

//
// POST:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditComputer(COMPUTER computer)
{
    Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    var result = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    try
    {
        IDataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
        dataProvider.UpdateComputer(computer);
        return RedirectToAction("EditRoom/" + computer.Room.RoomID);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(computer);
    }
}
```

Computer model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebClientDLL
{
    public class COMPUTER
    {
        int _computerID;
        IPAddress _addressIP;
        PhysicalAddress _addressMAC;
        String _namePC;
        ROOM _room;

        public int ComputerID
        {
            get { return _computerID; }
            set { _computerID = value; }
        }

        public IPAddress AddressIP
        {
            get { return _addressIP; }
            set { _addressIP = value; }
        }

        public PhysicalAddress AddressMAC
        {
            get { return _addressMAC; }
            set { _addressMAC = value; }
        }

        public String NamePC
        {
            get { return _namePC; }
            set { _namePC = value; }
        }

        public ROOM Room
        {
            get { return _room; }
            set { _room = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Room model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebClientDLL
{
    public class ROOM
    {
        int _roomID;
        String _roomName;
        String _building;

        public int RoomID
        {
            get { return _roomID; }
            set { _roomID = value; }
        }

        public String RoomName
        {
            get { return _roomName; }
            set { _roomName = value; }
        }

        public String Building
        {
            get { return _building; }
            set { _building = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebClientDLL.COMPUTER

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edycja komputera";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Komputer</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ComputerID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Room)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Room.RoomID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Room.RoomName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Room.Building)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NamePC)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NamePC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NamePC)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressIP)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressIP)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressIP)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressMAC)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressMAC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressMAC)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Powrót do sali", "EditRoom/" + @Model.Room.RoomID)
    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I'm getting from first two lines in EditComputer POST action:

```
__RequestVerificationToken=pZR5DUClnJ...
&ComputerID=4
&Room=WebClientDLL.ROOM
&Room.RoomID=1
&Room.RoomName=L2.200
&Room.Building=C-x
&NamePC=PECETx
&AddressIP=192.168.0.24
&AddressMAC=1122334456
```

Although all of these fields are correct (as you can see in the post field above), the Room field in COMPUTER parameter in post action is null. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a few days I managed to find out what's wrong. Obviously it was @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Room) - mvc thought it's a string and since I'm not doing any validation yet, it didn't tell me anything. The solution is to implement interface IModelBinder:

```
public class COMPUTER : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        return new COMPUTER();
    }
}
```

and put this in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(COMPUTER), new UserModelBinder());
```